# Mesh simplification in three.js

Tags: three.js, mesh, triangulation, simplification

I am using the Constructive Solid Geomery library for Three.js, made by Chandler Prall.

https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG

The resulting meshes are accurate, but they are very fragmented (lots and lots of unnecessary triangles), and they break some functionality in Three.js, for example the EdgesHelper class is not able to find the edges anymore. This problem is also mentioned here:

http://moczys.com/2014/01/13/three-js-experiment-3-additive-geometry/

Is there a mesh simplification library for Three.js that can take care of this? Perhaps there already is a polygon union function (merge all co-planar adjacent triangles into a 2D Shape), which then can be triangulated back into 3D again?